# Windows 10 DNS Lookup returns incorrect response

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, bind

I have a user on a Windows 10 machine that is getting very odd responses to a DNS query.  I'm running bind9 and using zones to separate internal and external queries based on subnets and it works perfectly for every other user but this one laptop.

When I run an nslookup on their machine for the mail server, I am getting the external IP (non-authorative):

```
C:\Users\franc>nslookup mail.example.com.
Server:  ns2.example.com
Address:  10.0.0.60

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    mail.example.com
Address:  163.237.18.117
```

However, when I enabled query logging on the server, I see that bind is correctly seeing the query as coming from the internal zone:

```
client 10.0.0.193#52796: view internal: query: 60.0.0.10.in-addr.arpa IN PTR + (10.0.0.60)
client 10.0.0.193#52800: view internal: query: mail.example.com IN A + (10.0.0.60)
client 10.0.0.193#52802: view internal: query: mail.example.com IN AAAA + (10.0.0.60)
```

If I connect the laptop to an external network connection, the external DNS works and of course the mail client works again.

I tried clearing the DNS cache on the machine, no change on the answer.  As far as I can tell the server is correctly answering the query as an internal view, so I have no idea where Windows is getting the external view answer.  It isn't restricted to just the mail address - any internal name lookup is returning an external view answer.

Comment: What do the records look like for mail.example.com in the internal zone?

Comment: Do you mean what do they look like in the zone file or what the answer is?

Comment: in the zone file

Comment: $INCLUDE /var/named/SOA
    ;
    @               IN              MX              10 mail
    mail            IN              A               10.0.0.60